# Use javascript comma separated variable to repopulate a forms checkbox values when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery variable that is storing a comma separated list of id names.  I need help writing something in jquery that separates that variable and uses those values to populate a forms checkbox values when the page loads.

so my jquery variable is $storedFormValues that is a comma separated list of values "checkbox1, checkbox, etc."

and my form

```
<form name="formname" id="formid">
<input type='checkbox' class='catcheck' id='checkbox1' value='checkbox1' name='catselect' />Checkbox 1
<input type='checkbox' class='catcheck' id='checkbox2' value='checkbox2' name='catselect' />Checkbox 2
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var $storedFormValues = "checkbox3,checkbox5";

$(function() {
    $.each($storedFormValues.split(","), function(intIndex, objValue) {
        $("#" + objValue).attr("checked", "true");
    });
})
```

See the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/xNyww/

Answer (score 1):

Not jQuery, but plain JS: You can use split to separate the values in an array:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

I do not know what do the csv looks like. If it's only one line, e.g:

checkbox1, checkbox7, checkbox2

then use it as:

```
var checkboxes[] = csvString.split(",");

for (str in checkboxes) {
    $("#"+str).yourActionHere();
}
```

If it's several lines (one per checkbox) , e.g.

```
checkbox1, true
checkbox2, false
```

then :

```
var checkboxes[] = csvString.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);

for (str in checkboxes) {
    var data = str.split(",");
    $("#"+data[0]).yourActionHere(data[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qBXHG/)**

```
var storedFormValues = "checkbox1, checkbox3, checkbox4";

$('#formid').children('input[id^=checkbox]').each(function() {
    if (storedFormValues.indexOf($(this).attr('id')) != -1) {
        $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
});
```

**Note:** If you plan on having more than 10 checkboxes, I recommend naming them with a leading zero (ex: `checkbox01`) otherwise you may run into an issue where `checkbox1` matches against `checkbox11`.