# How to store variables into Array which is stored into another Array (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, arrays, variables

for a project I'm working on there are several buttons which open different modal popup windows. Each of these windows have their own checkboxes.

After a user selects some checkboxes and then closes the modal, the checkbox information is stored in an array and displayed on the page.

My problem is that when the user reopens the same modal popup window I need those same checkboxes to be filled out. I've found a [stackoverflow question which covers this here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793538/use-javascript-comma-separated-variable-to-repopulate-a-forms-checkbox-values-wh)

However my issue is that it seems that I have to create a unique variable/array and then put that Array into a main array and I'm not sure how to do that.

```
// id of the button so I can use the name to open unique popups
// and create unique variable names
var roleId = '';

// The main Array to store all my button/checkbox lists Arrays into
var storedArray = [];    

// The Array that stores the currently selected checkbox items.
var selectedArray = [];


// The function that is on all the buttons that bring up the checkbox modals
$('.role').click(function(){

    // Saves a unique ID to be used to open up the appropriate popup
    roleId = $(this).attr('tag');

    // Here I try to create a Variable for a unique Array
    storedArray.push('stored'+roleName);

    // Selects the appropriate Modal popup
    $('#modal-'+roleId).modal();
    return false;
});

// Later the function that saves the checkbox items that are selected:
    $('input:checked').each(function() {
        selectedArray.push($(this).val());
    });

// Where I try to store the checkbox data into the
// storedArray which is inside the slected Array
    storedArray.push(selectedArray);
    console.log('2 storedArray = '+storedArray);
```

Comment: What modal library are you using?

Comment: Simple Modal http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for SimpleModal, there is a `persist` option. Does this do what you want?

```
$('#modal-'+roleId).modal({persist:true});
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much :) didn't even think about that possible function